# Porque me marca error en los else if

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Intento hacer que cuando se escriba la enfermedad escriba que tiene la enfermedad pero me marca error y si le quito la función de `strcmp` no funciona como esperaba.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
float imc(float altura, float peso);
int main()
{
    float carb, prot, lip, calor1, calor2, calor3, calort;
    char padecimiento[20];
    int op2;
    char op3[5];
    char op[5];
    char op1[2];
    float edad, peso, altura, IMC, altura2;
    char nombre[100];
    char AF[100];
    char alergia;
    int alergia1;
    char enfermedad;

    cout << setw(50) << "Bienvernido Usuario Nuevo" << endl;
    cout << "\n" << setw(60)
         << "Ingrese los siguientes datos requeridos: " << endl;
    cout << "ingrese su nombre" << endl;
    cin.getline(nombre, 100, '\n');
    cout << "Ingrese su edad: " << endl;
    cin >> edad;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Mencione las actividades físicas que usted realiza:" << endl;
    cin.getline(AF, 100, '\n');
    cout << "¿Desea sacar su Indice de masa corporal? " << endl;
    cin >> op;
    if (strcmp(op, "si") == 0) // La función strcmp compara dos stringsy retorna 0
    // que indica la relación entre ellas.
    {
        cout << "Ingrese su peso: " << endl;
        cin >> peso;

        cout << "ingrese su altura: " << endl;
        cin >> altura;

        if (imc(altura, peso) < 25 && imc(altura, peso) > 18.4) {
            cout << "Su imc es de" << IMC << "es normal" << endl;
        }
        if (imc(altura, peso) >= 25 && imc(altura, peso) < 30) {
            cout << "Usted tiene sobrepeso" << endl;
        }
        if (imc(altura, peso) >= 30) {
            cout << "Usted tiene obesidad" << endl;
        }
        if (imc(altura, peso) <= 24.9) {
            cout << "Usted está bajo de peso" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "¿Cuantas alergias tiene de las siguientes?" << endl;
    cout << "\t Huevos \t Marsicos \t Manies \n\t Nueces \t Trigo \t\t Leche "
            "\n\t Cacahuates \t Almendras \t Ajo"
         << endl;
    cout << "\t Ciruelas \t Papa \t\t Pimiento \n\t Cebolla \t Especias" << endl;
    cin >> op2;

    char enfermedad[20];
    cout << "¿Padece alguna de las siguientes enfermedades?" << endl;
    cout << "\b"
         << "\t Diabetes \t Asma \t Hipertension \n\t Hipotension \t Artritis \t "
            "Higado graso"
         << endl;
    cout << "(Tome en cuenta que debe escribir las enfermedades tal y como "
            "aparecen arriba)"
         << endl;
    cin.getline(op3, 20, '\n');
    if (strcmp(op3, "si") == 0) {
        cout << "ingrese cuales de esas enfermedades tiene:" << endl;
        cin >> enfermedad;
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Diabetes") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene diabetes" << endl;
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Asma") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene asma" << endl;
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Hipertension") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene hipertension" << endl;
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Hipotension") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene hipotension" << endl; //"\t Diabetes \t Asma \t
            // Hipertension \n\t Hipotension
            //\t Artritis \t Higado graso"
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Artritis") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene artritis" << endl;
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Higado graso") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene hígado graso" << endl;
        }
        if (strcmp(enfermedad, "Diabetes y Asma") == 0) {
            cout << "usted tiene diabetes y asma " << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Usted no tiene enfermedades" << endl;
    }
    // Diabetes \t Asma \t Hipertension \n\t Hipotension \t Artritis \t Migraña
    // \n\t Higado graso"                        <<endl;

    cout << "¿Desea calcular las caloria de su alimento?" << endl;
    cin >> op1;
    if (strcmp(op1, "si") == 0) {
        cout << "1 g  de carbohidratos = 4 kcal" << endl;
        cout << "1 g  de proteínas = 4 kcal" << endl;
        cout << "1 g  de lípidos(grasas) = 9 kcal" << endl;

        cout << "Ingrese el número de carbohidratos que tiene su alimento:" << endl;
        cin >> carb;

        cout << "Ingrese el número de proteínas que tiene su alimento:" << endl;
        cin >> prot;

        cout << "Ingrese el número de lípidos(grasas) que tiene su alimento:"
             << endl;
        cin >> lip;

        calor1 = carb * 4;
        calor2 = prot * 4;
        calor3 = lip * 9;
        calort = calor1 + calor2 + calor3;

        cout << "Su alimento tiene" << setw(5) << calor1 << setw(10)
             << "Kcal de carbohidratos" << endl;

        cout << "Su alimento tiene" << setw(5) << calor2 << setw(10)
             << "Kcal de proteinas" << endl;

        cout << "Su alimento tiene" << setw(5) << calor3 << setw(10)
             << "Kcal de lípidos(grasas)" << endl;

        cout << "Su alimento tiene" << setw(5) << calort << setw(10)
             << "Kcal en total" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

float imc(float altura, float peso)
{
    float altura2, IMC;
    altura2 = pow(altura, 2);
    IMC = peso / altura2;
}
```

Comment: Sugerencia: en lugar de llamar una función con los mismos parámetros reiteradas veces, guarda el resultado en una variable. Por ejemplo con `imc(altura, peso)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Este compilador](https://tio.run/##rVjNbttGEL7rKQYqkEitauvHLppItpE6DWI0LgIkOTk5jMi1tCm5y@wuE6SBH6YP4EPRWy8FqgdzZ3dJiaRIWVKjg0TNzsw3Mzs/uwyS5PsgQjG7u/uGiyBKQwYTLrVRDOPT1ooWEImLWYkUo5kXCVzGKHhy2mqlmnhBYMx0ggEDbcJxq3UdSTTA46DjnzAyqcIe@H8J07I7bnFhIEYuOt3WlxbQx68GqKY9SJQ0PYh40iNCJNUg@x1mv6Ps14ydaDBHBQmGLOAxZ8LIq2H/nV@yMDIZFvhkMro6flciVP8ProYZwRvFQgx7zvDe0pmLy/P8T1G7kPFUsatBv19U@eRZlYIRUzOOKyMzwqDAw8Q1U7EFp6A6qkwNTCagmfnUOe537XP7J/L4I1OChxLe6BQVl/Bryj7Ktl1mIozGJeH2W9FeKvmh33WL7mMXL8RMMc0gkho0n6U2nExDiIYIin1ImSIg/RiatPNMgU6zWFQZuTiYMRNxwTqeoQcUmx48fCsedivKLlbKbBjWUbmA01PwIcq185mQinWqui6ZCLgU5BpqwMDwj5zEyLfrxa3mARHJOUi1YSE5ihH/HR9vsP3Jsw12//vPUzIbQSPls7X@QoSc6oOqJ0aNxKgSqTA6a3BIJlliXEOHCjKIk46kWmhr3u7CyQnQ1h8ewguE65ScWvwlwHOR4jhBhRDa7XOVrD@TN0YqgdB3OknQOsqtRUjBoOUIvRLaa8WARRShA8f7ZZkcdVtiC2JtSwpe2PUsc5tSxBfQJiWeo6DGxsT2lrwQXT@BCQyP4cEDWF85hcGPB0fdgi8lY16lVgZsjvtUpcJ2C0ShPIoxqrHt5h5rTk8azZnAqN9ozBuXfYaKjqIjqTaszH74W6LIKdO2DvYAmZCTRweP7oFh2iz@gCm@lzb7N/pz06pW0XmKwthy9c1RZ0aHvohX/emssdcZeG57oQZ6ukRFhZ4/C047/FbQM3XLgDnqa8Vnkh7o8QUL5gzaJdfajv2cinqeovEiT6KYcBX6P@9lu9RP60065yplkRd5iQl6xJfZ8PJGnbOppEK0LD/rhCYb6qZeMczHQ3lorIZgIaIv7ZRkFNBZSh1hLZAF8U1RnZa9tD495ThleUx07Ax/zhOmDBOa@q73iihySSBGRT3KcCdUCfVzPkOaaDOK7P0x7byWMTUuAUFKbqBrcCGbEkkHik@5cm4WfQODEXy2/VJWkWlDFMVIACqSxW4jemEa0KGiB8PyNCg171G5e39p7opBStluuxEZv2a0Tf/Hzc2yeGIoFm9mxmqZrMk3rMamkl1poVuEucx93aIO0GbFLmBo@fcBKqbdLoDzotyewHI/XLkGS3O6oaxKCmmab6yyCnOl5uqLbIutzHTstJ25zH6RLRi6S2gXtwXBfZCXG/AZdk3gcCVqcxk2DD77zSKq/prG4OeokJnWYkOoaLzJD3j/uxlfcorY4k/MFWb8xVg2fCYTb0/9gZhubUEaoe/H7grH3RRyR0Ee2/F31jTmBjVtdXBvWx3ADCyCvVjKOadJbW8yJ3AEvwW1Z7s1SXsZZYtbgbuJRYvbxF6VOjZeqMlEeFQVbj5eswjE4u@YKbluvJ1u2RlxFbYNU8FKb49VcHdXICu6PdBagBrgWpX8qseOeFKEdm8NKOTWd/gWjsblpSEtWWtrlka0RMpo5VFlxTh9TvF3uZrsYVTn9quVF96v1b372N3dM2U5cVC8jOdHq1@IaS0FNqbQdrDD7WBdNnCBXwNytB1kNS@@ArLZApkOfEaatdrOLiV0h06VgP64dbPVC67SS63sNZF7aeS1ZhSbhfLT8l41zE6O9gp64vTA4eod083d3X8) indica el error:

> .code.tio.cpp:65:10: error: redefinition of 'enfermedad' with a
> different type: 'char [20]' vs 'char'
> char enfermedad[20];

Porque al inicio de la función `main` ya definiste una variable con el nombre `enfermedad`. Con borrar esta línea del comienzo se arregla:

```
char enfermedad;
```